# Weird space showing in font in IOS only - what could be triggering this?

Tags: css, fonts

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I have a website that uses a font with ligatures, and for some reason, ONLY in IOS (in both Safari and Chrome), there is a large gap showing between certain letters (see image). I've been told that this issue might be being caused by the way the ligatures are being rendered, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

You can view the problem on the website at: http://kaizenmedia.co/coda-signature-edibles/.

Apologies in advance, because my typography vocabulary is very limited so I'm not sure that I'm articulating the problem clearly.

Does anybody know why this might be happening and how I might be able to troubleshoot? Any help or ideas is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an iOS font-kerning issue which appears from time to time with, as you mentioned in your question, font with ligatures. I turned on the web inspector and tried debugging connecting my iPhone to Mac and found that and words that have 'fl' together face this issue. I tried replacing 'Truffles' with 'fluffy', 'flies', 'floop' etc. and the problem persists. I haven't tested if any other letter combination faces the same problem.

I notice that you have `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important` in your code-signature-edibles.css. Try changing it to `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed`, at least for this particular selector.

Comment: That seems to have solved it! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.